# Need value of datepicker as part of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to have the value from a datepicker to a part of a variable. The value from the datepicker must be inserted instead of `getAge("02/20/2017")` in the this code. the date has to be changed when datepicker is used, then "leeftijd" chages as well of course

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
  var birthdate = new Date(dateString).getTime();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var n = (now - birthdate) / 1000;
  if (n < 604800) { // less than a month
    var week_n = Math.abs(n / 604800).toFixed(2);
    return week_n;
  } else if (n < 63113852) { // less than 24 months
    var month_n = Math.abs(n / 2629743).toFixed(2);
    return month_n;
  }
}
var age = getAge("02/20/2017");
document.getElementById("age").value = age;
```

```html
<form name="id">
  <input id="age" class="appTextfield" type="text" name="element1" placeholder="age" value="">
  <input id="weight" class="appTextfield" type="text" name="element2" placeholder="weight" value="">
  <p>Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" size="30" onchange="getAge()"></p>
</form>
```

I tried lots of things but i can't get it to work... i must be doing something wrong. Any solutions to get it working?

Comment: Are you trying to work out the age of the user from the entered date? If so your logic is incorrect and can be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
  var birthdate = new Date(dateString).getTime();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var n = (now - birthdate) / 1000;
  if (n < 604800) { // less than a month
    var week_n = Math.abs(n / 604800).toFixed(2);
    return week_n;
  } else if (n < 63113852) { // less than 24 months
    var month_n = Math.abs(n / 2629743).toFixed(2);
    return month_n;
  }
}
function calculateAge(dateString) {
        var age = getAge(dateString);
        document.getElementById("age").value = age;
    }
```

```html
<form name="id">
  <input id="age" class="appTextfield" type="text" name="element1" placeholder="age" value="">
  <input id="weight" class="appTextfield" type="text" name="element2" placeholder="weight" value="">
  <p>Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" size="30" onchange="calculateAge(this.value)"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you. I'm definitely not good in javascript, tried to do it all in one function, but this is way easier and works great. Exactly what i needed.